# Mac software for live concerts\events

Tags: macos, presentations

I have a Mac, a projector and a lot of sound equipment.

I need at the time – according to the scenario – run different sounds, videos and pictures, also maybe live video from a camera, but I can not find a better solution.

Before I use Windows, and had to run videos and sounds in ordinary players. It's not convenient. Now I have a Mac, and am looking for a good solution.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense now. Thanks for clarifying. I updated your question to include that. I'm not aware of any solution at the moment, but maybe I'll find  something.

Answer (score 1):

How about using some VJ software such as;

http://resolume.com/software/

or

http://cogevj.hu/